# Cannot edit externally hosted SQL database from Lightswitch application

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have setup a Lightswitch 2012 application (locally for the moment). When I access an "external" SQL Server 2012 database hosted locally, I have no problem with accessing tables and adding, deleting or editing data from tables.

However, once I connect the Lightswitch Data Source to the same database, but hosted on a hosted server, I can connect and read data absolutely fine.....but I can't add, delete or even edit any data in any of the tables. This same problem occurs with a SQL Server 2008 R2 databse as well.

Is there something obvious (or not) that I need to do in order to allow editing of an externally hosted SQL Server database.

Comment: Do you have separate database users for your "User Connection" connect string and your "Publish Database Schema" connect string? What are the Role Memberships in SSMS for each user?

Comment: Does the account in the user connection string have permission to add/edit records to the database tables? (Another way of asking "What are the Role Memberships in SSMS for each user?")